# NodeJs does not start

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

Edit: I changed the title for this question because it seemed more accurate.

So this is my package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "application-name",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
 "dependencies": {
 "express": "~4.0.0",
 "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
 "morgan": "~1.0.0",
 "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
 "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
 "debug": "~0.7.4",
 "jade": "~1.3.0",
 "mongodb": "*",
 "monk": "*"
 }
}
```

I don't really get an error after hitting npm install but it seems like node didn't install all dependencies. Because when we hit the exact same code on my collegue's pc his promt said a lot more feedback on installed dependencies and it worked fine there.

**When i now hit "npm start" it just terminates after a few seconds without any response**.

I know there is a bug with node at the moment and i already tried to clear my npm chache and adding the "npm update" command and it still doesn't work.

It seems like its a problem with my pc because, like i said, on my collegue's pc everything worked fine. I hope you have any ideas what could be the problem. Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: Here's what the npm list command gives me:

```
├─┬ body-parser@1.0.2
│ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ ├─┬ raw-body@1.1.3
│ │ └── bytes@0.2.1
│ └─┬ type-is@1.1.0
│   └── mime@1.2.11
├─┬ cookie-parser@1.0.1
│ ├── cookie@0.1.0
│ └── cookie-signature@1.0.3
├── debug@0.7.4
├─┬ express@4.0.0
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.0.0
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ └── negotiator@0.3.0
│ ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
│ ├── cookie@0.1.0
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.3
│ ├── debug@0.8.0
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.1
│ ├── fresh@0.2.2
│ ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
│ ├── methods@0.1.0
│ ├── parseurl@1.0.1
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.2
│ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ ├── range-parser@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ send@0.2.0
│ │ ├── debug@0.8.0
│ │ └── mime@1.2.11
│ ├─┬ serve-static@1.0.1
│ │ └─┬ send@0.1.4
│ │   ├── debug@0.8.0
│ │   ├── fresh@0.2.0
│ │   ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │   └── range-parser@0.0.4
│ ├─┬ type-is@1.0.0
│ │ └── mime@1.2.11
│ └── utils-merge@1.0.0
├─┬ jade@1.3.1
│ ├── character-parser@1.2.0
│ ├── commander@2.1.0
│ ├─┬ constantinople@2.0.0
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.13
│ │   ├── async@0.2.10
│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.33
│ │   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ ├─┬ monocle@1.1.51
│ │ └─┬ readdirp@0.2.5
│ │   └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │     ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │     └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ transformers@2.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ css@1.0.8
│ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.0.4
│ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ promise@2.0.0
│ │ │ └── is-promise@1.0.0
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5
│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.33
│ │     └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ └─┬ with@3.0.0
│   └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.13
│     ├── async@0.2.10
│     ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│     ├─┬ source-map@0.1.33
│     │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│     └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
├─┬ mongodb@1.4.0
│ ├─┬ bson@0.2.7
│ │ └── nan@0.8.0
│ └── kerberos@0.0.3
├─┬ monk@0.8.1
│ ├── debug@0.8.0
│ ├─┬ mongoskin@0.4.4
│ │ └─┬ mongodb@1.1.11
│ │   └── bson@0.1.5
│ └── mpromise@0.4.4
├─┬ morgan@1.0.0
│ └── bytes@0.2.1
└── static-favicon@1.0.2
```

So it really looks like the dependencies have been installed (if I'm not completely wrong?). Still my "npm start" command terminates after just a few seconds... any guesses?

Comment: What do you get when you do `npm list`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer jeremy. I edited my Question so i could post my full list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the cursor is returning on node app.js(server.js or whatever the name of the js is) like shown below

```
c:/users/<project-path>:node app.js
c:/users/<project-path>:
```

Then you might be using express 4 generator 
So try the following command

```
set DEBUG=<project-folder-name>:* & npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cleared the npm cache, try also removing all folders in your app's `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.
 
You might want to try starting your app in `DEBUG` mode and see if it gives you any hint:

```
DEBUG=express:* node ./bin/www
```

Comment: Ok now im really starting to feel dumb. I tried your first two methods and they didn't work. 
When I try to set the DEBUG variable my prompt says that DEBUG is unknown although I hit "npm install debug". Sorry if this seems to be stupid...

Comment: Hmm. If you have express installed, then you should already have the debug module. No need to install it separately. If it isn't there, then it might be that express module is missing. Does it happen only with this particular app, or any node application? Can you try copying this `package.json` to a new dir and execute `npm install` from there? What does terminal tell you?

Comment: Thanks for your help Alexander!
Yeah every Node app doesn't start. But on my collegue's the DEBUG command is also unknown. Maybe we're just doing it wrong?
If I switch the direction and install my npm there it says exactly the same :S

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is not a direction, but a folder. Try creating a new folder somewhere in your home directory, say `~/temp/myapp`, then copy your `package.json` there. Then open a terminal window, go to your newly created folder and execute `npm install`. What is the output of the terminal? Is it fetching the modules from the remote server or is nothing happening?

Comment: It says the exact same things as before. It seems to have installed all the dependencies and ends with "> kerberos@0.0.3 install D:\test\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)"

Comment: Should be fine. Please, try a one-liner to check that node is working:
`$ node -e \
'console.log("ok")'`
If the console returns `ok`, then try running your app from node, rather than through npm script.

Comment: I already try to start node with my terminal or what did you mean?
To your command. Seems like it doesn't work on windows, im not really into that command thing to be honest so I don't really know how to fix the error... my terminal says:
[eval]:1
\
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at evalScript (node.js:532:25)
    at startup (node.js:80:7)

What do I have to change?

Comment: Try to open your app directory and run `node your-js-file.js` instead of `npm start`. A one-liner should work under Windows as well: open termnial, then write `node -e 'console.log("ok")'` without "\" and press `Enter`. But I expect it will work fine, since it evaluated the expression correctly and found a syntax error.

Comment: When I hit your command as you suggested I dont get any output at all, just like when I hit npm start. I think "node my-js-file.js" doesn't work in NodeJSv4 anymore they changed it to npm start

Comment: Well, node is separate from npm manager and should be able to start your app. Can you please tell me the folder structure of your app? I am interested in your main JS file. Where is the file which is the primary entry point of your program located in your folder? Is it in the root directory? Whenever you run `npm start`, your script field (inside `package.json`) is telling node to execute a file called `www` inside `bin` folder in your app directory.

Comment: Yeah its in the root directory, when I hit "node app.js" btw I just get the same result as before... nothing :(.
The crazy thing is, I can make it run on any computer except for mine.

Comment: If it is in the root, then you need to change your npm script to `"start": "node app.js"`, otherwise `npm start` will fail with no feedback. Unfortunately, there is something wrong with your node setup, since `node app.js` should definitely work. Please, check that `node -v` and `npm -v` show you proper versions.

Comment: This is what my promt gives me with node -v and npm -v:
D:\node
v0.10.2

D:\node
1.4.3

If I change my script zo "start": "node app.js" I got the same result as before:
D:\node\depTest>npm start

> application-name@0.0.1 start D:\node\depTest
> node ./bin/www

> application-name
> node ./bin/www


D:\node\depTest>
So it just terminates again...

Comment: If your code is exactly the same, as on your colleague's PC, which is working, then it must be something with Node. Try adding a latest stable version. You can use `n` to switch between different versions of node: `npm install -g n`, then add the latest stable build `n 0.10.28` (it should be using the latest node now, check with `node -v`, if not, then just switch it by running `n`). Then try running your app again.

Comment: This would resolve the issue if there is an issue with any of packages. In my case the issue is with `mongodb` package.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is resolved or ignored and found a workaround. Just had gone through the problem myself and found out that the problem was not with NodeJS but with one of the dependencies. I failed to install ejs and all my files are ejs based. So I got the same error as you.

So it is best to check if all your dependencies are installed properly.

Comment: What does ejs have to do with the question? The author never mentioned ejs.

Comment: I'm giving an example. The author might be using anything else which he may haven't installed. The exact same thing happened for me because ejs wasn't installed. Just wanted to do any help possible. Please remove if it is irrelevant. I'm still beginner.

Comment: No that's fine. It's a fine answer by you should say something like "try looking for missing dependencies" so that people don't get confused by all the talk of unrelated ejs package.

Comment: I didn't know how to say. Will follow this in future. Thanks.